# Java IO transfer issue

Tags: java, io

A FileUtils class created to re-use for all IO.
We transfer files (random amount) over a share from one Unix server to another.

**My issue:**
At random one file will come through as a 0kb file, but no exceptions and says that it transferred successfully.

**Basic method we use:**

```
resultCode = 0;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(fileLocation + orginalFile);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(toFolder + destinationFile);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int i = 0;
        while ((i = fis.read(buf)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buf, 0, i);
        }

        resultCode = 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        resultCode = 2;
        //our logging

    } finally {
        try {
            fis.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
//our logging
        }
    }

    return resultCode;
}
```

Any ideas on what can be causing this? the FileUtils class is called each time for the individual file transfer.

Thank you

Comment: How do you close your streams ?

Comment: } finally {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {

It transfers all the files correctly but at random one file is 0kb, when i check the file to transfer its the correct size, happens randomly

Comment: I have updated the code in first post

Comment: Your code seems fine. Are you sure you are not receiving any exceptions??

Comment: fis.close();
fos.close(); 
Probably not the answer but if fis is null then fos may never be closed...

Answer (score 1):

flush the File output stream before closing [`fos.flush()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29), i am not sure it would solve your problem but its worth a try:

> **public void flush() throws IOException**
>
> Flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be
>   written out. The general contract of flush is that calling it is an
>   indication that, if any bytes previously written have been buffered by
>   the implementation of the output stream, such bytes should immediately
>   be written to their intended destination.

Comment: Will do, can you give me a little explination as to what this will do? the flush?

Regards

Comment: Will give it a go, Thank you all for the answers and keep well.